# Proof for Legendre polynomial

Tags: homework-and-exercises

For a Legendre polynomial prove that

$$\dfrac{1}{\mid\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}\mid}
=
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{r_i^l}{R^{l+1}} P_l(\hat{r}\cdot\hat{R}) $$

where $l$ orbital quantum number, $P$ is an $l$th-degree Legendre polynomial

Comment: That's a) off-topic as homework-like b) not a physics question.

Answer (score 2):

I think using generating function for legendre polynomial will work.